# Sqlite generate distance table from point information

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I have a table that contains coordinates of several points.

```
| PointName | XCoor | YCoor |
+-----------+-------+-------+
|    P1     |  X1   |  Y1   |
+-----------+-------+-------+
|    P2     |  X2   |  Y2   |
+-----------+-------+-------+
....
```

I want to generate a table that includes distance between two points.

```
| Point1Name | Point2Name | Distance |
+------------+------------+----------+
|    P1      |    P2      |  ZZZZZ   |
+------------+------------+----------+
....
```

To be able to calcualte the distance between two points, I enabled dynamic extension loading and used [extension-functions module](https://www.sqlite.org/contrib/download/extension-functions.c?get=25) for arithmetic calculations. However, I am not quite sure if it is possible to create the output table with any sort of SQL tricks?

I need this functionelity in a C++ program, so in the worst case I will try to do it in the C++ way rather than using an SQL statement. This ,however, will require me to use [sqlite3_exec()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) and define my callback function, and most probably I will end up running another [sqlite3_exec()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) within the first callback funstion to get the desired output.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This SQL should produce a table for you:

```
create table distances as
select a.PointName as Point1Name, b.PointName as Point2Name,
  sqrt((a.XCoor - b.XCoor) * (a.XCoor - b.XCoor) + (a.YCoor - b.YCoor) * (a.YCoor - b.YCoor)) as Distance
from points a, points b
where a.rowid != b.rowid
```

Do you really need it in a table though? You could just execute the select statement when you want to get the values.

Comment: Thanks! I will use this table for another operation, so I beter store it in the database rather than running the query each and every time!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
   a.PointName AS Point1Name,
   b.PointName AS Point2Name, 
   POWER(POWER(a.xCoor - b.xCoor, 2) + POWER(a.yCoor - b.yCoor, 2), 1 / 2) AS Distance
FROM
   Points a, Points b
WHERE
   a.PointName <> b.PointName
;
```

Will have each distance twice (p1 <-> p2 and p2 <-> p1)

Comment: wow, sqlite really has no power function, would work in oracle, mysql and more.

Comment: (so only the other answer is correct, I don't know if this one should be left here for people maybe finding it with other dbms or delete it)

Comment: Your answer is just as correct as mine - the extension library he is using has a `power` function.